# Why is "Никита" a typical masculine name?

Tags: грамматика, морфология

Since most feminine conjugations of Russian names, as well as nouns and adjectives either end with **a**, or **я**, I find it weird that Никита is a typical masculine name?

I'm wondering if it is just an "exception" on the rule, or whether there is a logical explanation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It comes from Greek masculine name Νικήτας meaning "victor". The Greek ending -ς is usually dropped in Russian so the word ends up with -α. This is similar to French masculine name Nicolas (which was also borrowed from Greek) where the final -s is not pronounced.

Answer (score 7):

Typically *short* from of masculine first names also end in `-а` or `-я`.
For instance:

- Дима
- Петя
- Вова, Володя
- *etc*

The following *full* form of masculine first names also end in `-а` or `-я`:

- Илья
- Добрыня
- Кузьма
- *etc*

So it is not weird.

Answer (score 6):

Russian nouns ending in **-а** or **-я** are *either* feminine or masculine.

> Feminine: мама, тётя, Наташа, Ольга, Светлана
>
> Masculine: папа, дядя, воевода, Никита, Данила, Серёжа, Саша, Коля, Петя

Comment: Very "nice" answer. I can't believe the other responders found it necessary to inform this person that "his assumption is just wrong." I never ceases to amaze me that someone can achieve such a good command of a language and not learn the finer points of communicating with the appropriate tone.

Answer (score -1):

Well, your assumption is just wrong. There are some word which are masculine though are ending at -a or -я. Like:

- Парнишка (or братишка or мишка, plus some other words ending on -ишка)
- Дядя
- Деда
- Мужчина
- Судья
- Юноша